# What steps are required to make the Xcode 8 Command Line Tools template build?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, xcode8

The template project for a MacOS command line tool does not build for me in XCode 8. This is the entire code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        // insert code here...
        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The failure happens on the import line. The start of the error output is reproduced below.

I have a fresh machine running El Capitan. I installed Xcode 8 from the GM download (not the app store) around a week ago.

What do I need to do to get this to build?

Error output:

```
In file included from /Users/ahcox/dev/macos/CommandLine001/CommandLine001/main.m:9:
In file included from /Users/ahcox/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:48:
In file included from /Users/ahcox/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSKeyedArchiver.h:9:
/Users/ahcox/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSGeometry.h:20:9: error: unknown type name 'CGPoint'; did you mean 'Point'?
typedef CGPoint NSPoint;
        ^
In file included from /Users/ahcox/dev/macos/CommandLine001/CommandLine001/main.m:9:
In file included from /Users/ahcox/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
In file included from /Users/ahcox/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:43:
In file included from /Users/ahcox/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFBase.h:77:
/Users/ahcox/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/include/MacTypes.h:542:41: note: 'Point' declared here
typedef struct Point                    Point;
                                        ^
...
```

Comment: Please vote to close. I'm basically asking how to install applications on MacOS in this question without realising it. Xcode was the first application I installed on my first Mac you see :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Install Xcode under `/Applications/`

Looking at these paths, Xcode is running directly from the Download directory in which it was unpacked from the GM seed xip file (i.e. it is in `"/Users/ahcox/Downloads/Xcode.app/"`). Either copy it to `/Applications/` manually or run the App Store app and let it install Xcode where it wants. To solve this problem for myself I did the latter.
More info on [installation of apps on MacOS](http://web.archive.org/web/20160328025809/http://www.howtogeek.com/177619/how-to-install-applications-on-a-mac-everything-you-need-to-know/).